# Show server counter on GUI while still in progress

Tags: c#, wcf, event-handling

My question is pretty simple, but I got lost somehow.
I have a project including ClientProject and ServerProject (WCF service application) contains my Service class and its interface.
The service runs method with few iterations.
All I need to do is to show on GUI the service's number of iteration on real time,
so that the user will be able to be aware to service activity state while running.

I've seen examples of declaring a delegate ServerEventHandler on service,
and registration to that event on client side.
 
For example:
 
**ServiceProject:**

```
public delegate void ServerEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event ServerEventHandler ServerEvent; <br/><br/>
```

**ClientProject:**

```
public Client(Server s)
{
    s.ServerEvent += new Server.ServerEventHandler(Subscribe);
}
```

But I can not figure out how can I implement it on my WCF project, since my client and server are separated projects so that the only way I can get my ServiceProject values on my ClientProject is through its ServiceReference.
I can't understand how can the client have the service instance, and how can it access the ServerEvent property through it.
What am I missing?
Do I have to mention anything on my contract?
 Or is there any other way to implement it?
I'd be thankful If you'll be able to help me..

Comment: you can implement WSDualHttpBinding which allows you to define callback contract..

Comment: Here is link which you can refer https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WCF-Sample-Service-with-41ef222f

Comment: Hi. I've already implemented it. but when I send callback - does the server process continue running? In addition, which value do I have to send  on that callback in order to implement the code above? I'd be glad to get any example..

Comment: Hmm yes, WCF comes with async variance for each operation..you can call asyn operation on Callback Operation so server process will keep running....Even callback will have DataContract so just create DataContract class which will hold all values which you want to show in UI..Imagine callback as Service exposed by client so that Server can notify client by calling appropriate operation....I will try to post some code later..

Comment: Well I tryed it, and it workes perfectly :) Thank you so much @Viru .

Comment: Great....Did not got time to post code but glad my suggestion worked...I will post my suggestion as my answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implement WSDualHttpBinding which allows you to define callback contract
WCF comes with async variance for each operation..you can call async operation on Callback Operation so server process will keep running....Even callback will have DataContract so just create DataContract class which will hold all values which you want to show in UI..Imagine callback as Service exposed by client so that Server can notify client by calling appropriate operation.